# How do I know if mpmath is using gmpy or gmpy2?

Tags: python, mpmath, gmpy

I know of

```
import mpmath as mp
print mp.libmp.BACKEND
```

but if I'm not mistaken it won't say if I'm using gmpy or gmpy2.

Also, I that every time you use a newer version of something you don't get the version number next to it but since I can `import gmpy` and `gmpy2` separately I'm a bit worried I may be using the older version of gmpy.

Thank you

UPDATE:

I also tried the following which confused / worried me.

```
import mpmath as mp
import gmpy as gm
import gmpy2 as gm2
print mp.mpf('1') == gm.mpf('1')
# Result is FALSE
print mp.mpf('1') == gm2.mpfr('1')
# Result is FALSE
print gm.mpf('1') == gm2.mpfr('1')
# Result is FALSE
print mp.mpf('1') == 1
# Result is TRUE
print gm.mpf('1') == 1
# Result is TRUE
print gm2.mpfr('1') == 1
# Result is TRUE
```

What the heck?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mpmath` will try to import `gmpy2` first.

While you can import both `gmpy` and `gmpy2` at the same time, it is not a supported scenario since `gmpy` and `gmpy2` aren't aware of each other.

I maintain both `gmpy` and and `gmpy2` but I consider `gmpy` to be obsolete and `gmpy2` should be used instead.

Comment: so I guess there is no way to know after the fact which of the two have been imported right?

Comment: Not really. If you have both on your system, `gmpy2` will be used.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it is possible because python records all the modules it has imported in a dictionary.  You can see it if you do

```
   import sys
   print(sys.modules)
```

This is a dictionary that allows it to see if it has previously imported a module, so it doesn't have to do it again when it sees an `import` statement.  For example, in my code I have `import numpy as np` in lots of places because any one of those places might be the first time python gets asked to import it.  But the import takes a long time, so python doesn't want to do that every time it sees that statement.  If `numpy` is in `sys.modules`, it just assumes it already knows what it needs to know and skips it.

So to answer your question, do this:

```
import mpmath
import sys
'gmpy2' in sys.modules.keys()
```

If you get `True`, you're using `gmpy2` somewhere.  And if `mpmath` and `sys` are the only things you've imported, it's probably safe to assume that `mpmath` is the one using `gmpy2`.