# Why is gmpy2 so slow at complex exponentiation?

Tags: python, exponentiation, mpmath, gmpy, mpc

I was using complex numbers in gmpy2 and noticed that it was slow. I narrowed it down the exponentiation operator. At first I thought it was just because it was complex. But then I compared it to mpmath which *uses* gmpy2 and it was so much faster:

```
# tested using gmpy2 2.0.8, mpmath 1.1.0, python 3.8.5
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = '''
import gmpy2 as gm
import mpmath

a1 = gm.mpc(-12.5, 34.125)
a2 = gm.mpc(17, -45.875)

b1 = mpmath.mpc(-12.5, 34.125)
b2 = mpmath.mpc(17, -45.875)
'''

# using gmpy2
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** a2', setup)
87.13848301399992
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** 2', setup)
40.478690218
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a1, 2)', setup)
40.70392542999991

# using mpmath
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** b2', setup)
51.799312732999965
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** 2', setup)
4.239320562999978
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(b1, 2)', setup)
4.293315565000057

# multiplication comparison
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 * a1', setup)
0.9900801109999975  # gmpy2
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 * b1', setup)
4.711916033999955  # mpmath
```

Pure complex exponentiation is incredibly slow, but mpmath is still some 40% faster than gmpy2. Since mpmath is Python I figured it would be much slower but that's clearly not the case. How is gmpy2 so slow here?

Comment: Are you sure `mpmath` is using `gmpy2`? The docs say `mpmath`'ll use `gmpy` if available, without mentioning `gmpy2` (could just be an oversight, one project sprang from the other). I don't know how much effort they've put into keeping up with the gmpy/gmpy2 releases, and they might not work with `gmpy2` given it presumably had some breaking changes in the 2.0 release.

Comment: Could you please check and paste version of python, gmpy2, ,mpmath. Also please check if all C-libraries, that [gmpy2 depends](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#requirements) are properly compiled and installed. The results you have for single operation are **terribly** slow for both libraries,  I guess the issue is with C-libraries that works under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice versions are already there. Still I think you should check e.g. if `libmpfr` and `libmpfr-dev` (assuming its debian or similar, or equivalent appropriate for your OS) is properly installed and works properly

Comment: @ShadowRanger `mpmath.libmp.BACKEND` says `gmpy` even though gmpy is not installed - mpmath will also [try to import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26553032/1846249) `gmpy2` first.

Comment: @running.t gmpy2 was installed from a complied wheel file from [this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy) as I am on Windows.

Comment: `mpmath` will attempt to use `gmpy2` or `gmpy` to replace Python's built in integer type. `mpmath` does not call the `mpfr` or `mpc` related functions in `gmpy2`/`gmpy`. I'll look at in more detail later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

I was curious about the cause(s) of the differences. I ran four different tests.

```
# Reference test on Windows 10 that used the same gmpy2
# binaries.

>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** a2', setup)
60.565931600000006
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** 2', setup)
25.686232700000005
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a1, 2)', setup)
25.684606899999977
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** b2', setup)
35.29716189999999
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** 2', setup)
2.6226074000000494
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(b1, 2)', setup)
2.6126720999999975
>>>
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.version()
'2.0.8'
>>> gmpy2.mp_version()
'MPIR 2.7.2'
>>> gmpy2.mpfr_version()
'MPFR 3.1.4'
>>> gmpy2.mpc_version()
'MPC 1.0.3'
>>>
```

The results are similar to those in the question. I printed the versions of the underlying libraries.

```
# Test using WSL with latest Ubuntu version. Same physical
# system as above.

>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** a2', setup)
31.21574370000002
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** 2', setup)
2.3873958000000357
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a1, 2)', setup)
2.3556844999999953
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** b2', setup)
36.35650579999998
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** 2', setup)
2.4482329999999592
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(b1, 2)', setup)
2.431874800000003
>>>
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.version()
'2.1.0b3'
>>> gmpy2.mp_version()
'GMP 6.2.0'
>>> gmpy2.mpfr_version()
'MPFR 4.0.2'
>>> gmpy2.mpc_version()
'MPC 1.1.0'
>>>
```

I chose WSL because it is easy to install on Windows 10. `gmpy2` and `mpmath` were installed using `sudo apt install python3-gmpy2` and `sudo apt install python3-mpmath`. `gmpy2` is slightly faster than `mpmath`.

```
# Test using Hyper-V virtual machine under Windows Server 2016.
# Different physical system but identical specifications.

>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** a2', setup)
27.467059508984676
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** 2', setup)
2.171035467006732
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a1, 2)', setup)
2.193065536994254
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** b2', setup)
31.870763173996238
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** 2', setup)
2.019194034015527
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(b1, 2)', setup)
2.0843256690131966
>>> 
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.version()
'2.1.0b5'
>>> gmpy2.mp_version()
'GMP 6.2.0'
>>> gmpy2.mpfr_version()
'MPFR 4.0.2'
>>> gmpy2.mpc_version()
'MPC 1.1.0'
>>>
```

I used the latest beta release for the previous test. The results are identical with the Ubuntu version. Overall, slightly faster that WSL.

```
# Same as above but using gmpy2 2.0.8 instead of 2.1.0b5.

>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** a2', setup)
23.692542312986916
>>> timeit.timeit('a1 ** 2', setup)
9.208024947001832
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a1, 2)', setup)
9.388882965984521
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** b2', setup)
32.078784318000544
>>> timeit.timeit('b1 ** 2', setup)
2.027712993003661
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(b1, 2)', setup)
2.123160599003313
>>> 
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.version()
'2.0.8'
>>> gmpy2.mp_version()
'GMP 6.2.0'
>>> gmpy2.mpfr_version()
'MPFR 4.0.2'
>>> gmpy2.mpc_version()
'MPC 1.1.0'
>>>
```

The last two test show the difference between the `2.0.8` and `2.1.0` versions. I made significant changes to the argument handling. `mpc ** int` is much faster but `mpc ** mpc` is slightly slower. (I think I can fix that regression...)

The Windows binaries are using old versions of the underlying libraries. I am working towards Windows binaries based on the latest versions of GMP, MPFR, and MPC compiled with the mingw-w64 compilers. The GCC compiler will allow GMP to automatically select the proper code path for different CPUs.

Update 1

I've optimized `mpc ** mpc` and `mpc ** int`. The performance regression for `mpc ** mpc` has been fixed and `mpc ** int` is even faster.

Comment: So ultimately, it's slow because it's outdated. When might the `2.1.0` version be out? Unrelated: the Windows version (the compiled wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy) at least) also crashes Python when `.conjugate` is called on an `mpc`.

Comment: I managed to get a running binary. It is about 25% faster but the WSL/Linux versions are faster. I haven' done any detailed testing so its not ready for release but I'm getting closer.